# Inaccurate values of x-axis in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a specific course (acceleration over time) using matplotlib. The plot works so far and is being shown (see image). J equals 35 and represents the derivative of acceleration over time (which in this case is a constant).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def limits_acc_course():
limits_acc_course.t1 = 0.14285714285714285
limits_acc_course.t2 = 0.14285714285714285 + 0.10714285714285715
limits_acc_course.t3 = 2*0.14285714285714285 + 0.10714285714285715
limits_acc_course.t4 = 2*0.14285714285714285 + 0.10714285714285715 + 0.5*0.24714285714285716

limits_acc_course()

t_end = 2*limits_acc_course.t4
t_1 = np.linspace(0, limits_acc_course.t1)
t_2 = np.linspace(limits_acc_course.t1, limits_acc_course.t2)
t_3 = np.linspace(limits_acc_course.t2, limits_acc_course.t3)
t_4 = np.linspace(limits_acc_course.t3, limits_acc_course.t4)

tk1 = np.array([])
tk2 = np.array([])
tk3 = np.array([])
tk4 = np.array([])

for value1 in t_1:
    tk1 = np.append(tk1, value1*j)

for value2 in t_2:
    tk2 = np.append(tk2, limits_acc_course.t1*j)

for value3 in t_3:
    tk3 = np.append(tk3, (limits_acc_course.t3-value3)*j)

for value4 in t_4:
    tk4 = np.append(tk4, value4*0)
    if value4 == (2*limits_acc_course.t4-limits_acc_course.t3)*j:
        break

t = np.concatenate((tk1, tk2, tk3, tk4), axis=0)
t_neg = (-1)*np.concatenate((tk1, tk2, tk3), axis=0)

t_final = np.concatenate((t, t_neg), axis=0)   

t_range = np.linspace(0, t_end, t_final.size)


fig, t = plt.subplots()


t.plot(t_range, t_final)
t.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
plt.show()
```

The problem is that the x-coordinates in plot do not match the calculated values.

The x-values in the plot (see image)) should be: 
0.142857142857       0.25
(Or at least with such an accuracy:0.1429)

The x-values in the plot are.
0.144777             0.295348

I have tried to turn off the offset and i have played with range from 100 to 2500 values for each part and I have tried to round the values but it didn't work either. Further I have tried using endpoint=False in creating the ranges t_1 to t_4.

By now I ran out of ideas.

[image: Course of acceleration over time]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iMC7.png)

Comment: Please read and understand [mcve]. At the moment it is totally unclear what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry. I have changed it. I hope it is now clear what the problem is.

Comment: It is still not clear to me if you have an issue with calculation or visual representation. Also what is `j`?

Comment: It is about the visual representation of the x-values at the relevant points I have marked in the image.

Comment: Wouldn't a [mcve] then look like `plt.plot([0,0.142857142857,0.25,4], [0,4,4,-4])` ? How do you get the values `0.144777 0.295348` from the plot?

Comment: By using the cursor in the plot and the zoom. J  represents the Jerk and is in this example 35. Sorry. totally missed to explain J.

Comment: Is this a joke? You show a 50 line code to produce a plot which can be done in 3 lines, when the question is really about accuracy of the cursor?

Comment: It is not a joke. I was not sure what causes the problem and that's why I posted the code. I thought maybe the problem was somewhere else. I will not bother you anymore. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plot is created in an axes which will extent over ~500 pixels on screen. The x axis shows 1.1 units. Hence you have 1.1/500 = 0.0022 units per pixel. The mouse cursor cannot know its position more accurate than 1 pixel. Hence the coordiante shown by the mouse cursor is accurate to ~±0.0022 units.

The observed coordinate (0.144777) deviates from the actual coordinate (0.142857142857) by 0.0019 units, which is well within the accuracy of the cursor.